# What's the difference between a reactive stream, and an event listener?

Tags: javascript, stream, reactive-programming

Recently, in javascript, there's been a push towards reactive programming and making everything a stream that you can subscribe to.

However, what's the difference between subscribing to a stream, and subscribing to an event through an action listener?

Aren't both of these approaches "reactive" since they're both subscribing to clicks for example?

Comment: In streams, data can be `pushed` or `pulled` by the handlers, but in case of listeners, they are always `pushed` to the respective handlers.

Comment: A stream is a functor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both can be thought of as event processors, but the distinction/advantages come in various forms.

The first difference is in the form of an event listener vs. a stream. An event listener only handles a single event at a time. A reactive stream is a monad, meaning you can map functions over the events, emit new streams with transformed information, merge streams, compose streams, and more.

Second, referencing [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23853144/3772221), streams let you declare your variables as a result of events, keeping all your state logic in the same place.

```
counter := 0                               -- initial value

// ...
// Do other variable declarations, and bunch of other stuff.
// ... 

on buttonUp   = (counter := counter + 1)   -- change it later
on buttonDown = (counter := counter - 1)
```

Without streams you would keep your logic dictating the value of counter separate from the declaration of counter.

In contrast to something like this where everything you would ever need to know about counter is in one place:

```
counter :: Behavior Int
counter = accumulate ($) 0
            (fmap (+1) buttonUp
             `union` fmap (subtract 1) buttonDown)
```

Which in plain english says:

> counter is equal to 0 initially. Its value will be equal to accumulated result of two merged streams. One that returns +1 when the up button is pressed and one that returns -1 when the down button is pressed.